# Setting value for app.supported_locales parameter in services.yaml from a controller Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am using Symfony 5.4 .

I have added Translation with the help of the documentation.
https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/translation.html

I have hardcoded  app.supported_locales: 'en|es' in parameters (services.yaml).

In the header, there is a language switcher created by following https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/the-fast-track/en/28-intl.html#adding-a-locale-switcher.

The data for the drop down is coming from an API.
If the API return value the same result as app.supported_locales everything works fine.

But if API result(en,es,fr) is different from app.supported_locales , will get an error fr is not in the given app.supported_locales.

Tried to set the app.supported_locales from Controller via paramaterbag and got error

```
Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.
```

Can I update  app.supported_locales from controller or Is there any way I can solve my problem.